# Is there any way for CKEditor to just take in HTML Code AS IS (without auto adding extra tags or "fixing" markup)?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to edit code - in the source dialog. Which I imagine should be a workaround for people who want to be able to modify the HTML at a more granular level. However, it's still adding **extra tags** where I don't WANT them after it goes back to the WYSIWYG. I don't care for what's proper, since we have styling built around how the markup is.

For example:

```
<a href="link">
<img src="image">
<h3>Title</h3>
<div class="clear"></div>
</a>
```

Becomes:

```
<a href="link">
<img src="image">
</a>
<h3><a href="link">Title</a></h3>
<a href="link"></a>
<div class="clear"></div>
<a href="link"></a>
```